# Jetpack compose screenshot image

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to screenshot the below composable.

It currently nearly works, however the players on the screen's new position after they've been dragged don't appear in the screenshot.

The `FourFourTwo` and `FourFiveOneFormation` composables contain the `Player` composables.

```
var capturingViewBounds by remember { mutableStateOf<Rect?>(null) }

val context = LocalContext.current
var view = LocalView.current

Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top = 8.dp)
            .height(390.dp)
            .width(300.dp)
            .onGloballyPositioned {
                capturingViewBounds = it.boundsInRoot()
            },
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        when (currentFormation) {

            1 -> {
                FourFourTwoFormation(
                    state = state,
                    events = events
                )
            }

            2 -> {
                FourFiveOneFormation(
                    state = state,
                    events = events
                )
            }
        }

val bounds = capturingViewBounds ?: return@clickable
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
    bounds.width.roundToInt(), bounds.height.roundToInt(),
    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
).applyCanvas {
    translate(-bounds.left, -bounds.top)
    view.draw(this)
}
```

My player composable looks like this

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .offset { IntOffset(offsetX.value.roundToInt(), offsetY.value.roundToInt()) }
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                change.consumeAllChanges()
                offsetX.value = (offsetX.value + dragAmount.x)

                offsetY.value = (offsetY.value + dragAmount.y)
            }
        }
```

I want the screenshot to look like the left, but at the moment looks like the right

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a compose bug: seems like `view.draw` ignores `offset` with `IntOffset` as well as `graphicsLayer`. I've [reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/201753237) it, please star it to bring more attention.

Fortunately, it works fine with `offset` by `dp`, so you can use it that way for now:

```
val density = LocalDensity.current
// ...
.offset(
    x = with(density) { offsetX.value.toDp() },
    y = with(density) { offsetY.value.toDp() },
)
```